# HTMl5 and Canvas not drawing in IE9 (OR Firefox!)

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, internet-explorer-9

So I have been working on a map system for Canvas, it all works fine in Chrome.

But Firefox and IE9 refuse to draw anything to the canvas... I can't seem to work out why.
The FPS count in the document title still works ok.

Here is my code so far:
http://www.barriereader.co.uk/tmp/neuroTile/

Has anyone seen this sort of non-error before? Where only Chrome draws on the canvas?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by looking at the JavaScript console for error messages. It will tell you that document.width and document.height are not defined in IE9 or Firefox.

Comment: This sorted it out, it was because it couldn't find the document.width or window.width - so i used jquery $(window).width()